# trying to optimise the code and increasing performance by reading same text file from a method to different methods in java

Tags: java-7

Am trying to reducing the code and increasing performance by reading same text file from a method to different methods  in java.

sample code of reading text file in each every method based on requirement.

enter code here:

```
class{

main(){

method1();
method2();
method3();
....
}

method1(){

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.txt));
...
}

method2(){

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.txt));
...
}

method3(){

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.txt));
.....
}
}
```

what i want to know is there any logic to read text file once in one method and use in different method in java?

Comment: Before improving the performance, you have to know what are your actual performance and the bottleneck. Do you know? If yes, can you show these, please?

Comment: actally i dont know,but am trying to learn.                                                                        And in the above code am trying to read a web.txt file and it should be used where ever necessary.because reading same text file every time in every method then code will be more

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the file is immutable, you can:

- store his content, line by line, in a specific method
- this method is called by constructor
- the returned datas are stored in a *List* attribute of **class**
- and refer to this attribute by the other methods

  - method1()
  - method2()
  - method3()